# Accepting SSL certificates while accessing the application using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, desiredcapabilities

While accessing the application there is a browser notification appearing to select the certificate in order to proceed further and view the login page.
I need to run the tests in headless mode.

I tried couple of things to do this:

1. Using chrome capabilities - Even after setting the below properties it still shows the popup.

```
chromeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);
chromeOptions.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
```

2. Using parallel java threading - It is working sometimes and sometimes not without headless mode.
   In headless mode it is not even working once. Reference: [java threading](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-handle-self-signed-certificate-pop-up-in-selenium-using-java/)

```
 Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println("The Custom URL: " + strUrl);
                objDriverController.getDriver().get(strUrl);
            }
 });

 Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                autoClick();
            }
 });

 try {
            // start t1 thread that tries to open the URL
            t1.start();

            // start t2 thread that click on
            // the Enter button using Robot class
            t2.start();

            // Using below 2 lines we
            // run both the thread in parallel
            t1.join();
            t2.join();

            t2.interrupt();
            t1.interrupt();
        }
 catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

3. Editing Registry editor - It worked when browser opens, not in headless mode.

Selenium version - 4.1.1
Chrome version - 114.0.5735.199
Java Version - 17.0.6